# Book written in different colors depending on which narrator or character is "speaking"

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

If anyone is able to help with this you are truly amazing because the information I am about to give is barely any and not too reliable.

- I think there were at least 4 font colors in the book (green, red, blue and black), depending on the point of view or the character.
- I read this book when I was a teen (maybe?, like 15 years ago or more?).
- I don't remember the topic but something fantasy/adventure related.
- I read it in spanish but I don't know if it is a Spanish book or just a translation of other language.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange, could you clarify what parts of it are fantasy related for it to be on topic, and any relevant plot details that may help it be identified

Comment: Hi! I read it so long ago I barely remember anything, just the colors and the fact that it impacted me somehow... I posted it here because I saw some similar posts but please let me know if it would fit better somewhere else, I am new to all stackExchange and would really appreciate it :)

Comment: This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: @AMachado all it really needs to be on topic is a clarification on your end about which parts made it "fantasy" as at present there's nothing in your question to explain why/how it is fantasy.

Comment: House of Leaves uses different colors for certain words/phrases.

Comment: I remember we read Robert Leeson's "Red, White and Blue" in school - it's printed on three different colours (hence the title): "White is the official version, for his English homework. Red is to an imaginary penfriend and is the real truth. Blue is Wain's fantasy story the version he would like it to be."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possibly [*Legend*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_(Lu_novel)) by Marie Yu?  According to this [site](https://prezi.com/ygenopq4iefi/legend-by-marie-lu/), she uses at least two colors (black and gold) for two of the characters POV. Its publishing date of 2011 only makes it 12-13 years old, however.

Answer (score 5):

Well, certain editions of [The Neverending Story](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27712.The_Neverending_Story) used red for our world and green for Fantastica. See [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160425/which-in-print-editions-of-neverending-story-have-red-green-text). But that's only two colors, and I don't know if there was a Spanish edition like that.